# Detect Object Click in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

and Working on a Project.
I just wanted to know, **Is There any way to detect if a GameObject is clicked ?**

More precisely, *To Destroy an Object when it is Clicked.*
i.e.

```
if (Object_is_clicked) {
Destroy(this.gameObject);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the event system.

### Create a **MonoBehavior**

```
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class ClickDetector : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("Clicked: " + eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.name);
    }
}
```

### Attach to the game object you want to monitor

Check [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CreatingAndUsingScripts.html) on how to do it

You can you the generic `GameObject.AddComponent<Type>()` to do it in runtime.

Comment: Will it work in case of touch controls too (i.e. On Mobile Devices) ?

Comment: Yes it does. It's either click from a mouse or a touch from a screen.